# get line with matching text from external file using jquery

Tags: jquery, get, split, line, match

Ok so I have a list of links and when you hover them a 'popup' div is shown near the cursor. jQuery then loads an image inside that div based on the value of the query in the anchors `href`.

I am trying to make a plain text file with something similar to arrays that will hold a sentence or two describing information about that link/image. I have tried using `.match()` and `.split()` and have a little more luck using split. But still can't get it to do exactly what I need.

If anyone could give me a suggestion as to what I might be doing wrong that would be awesome!

Thanks in advance.

heres what my jQuery looks like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#pops a').hover(function(a) {
    var file = $(this).attr("href").match(/page=(.*)/)[1];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "about_links.txt",
        success: function(msg){
            var msgarray = (msg).split(file + " - ");
            var discr = msgarray["1"];

            $('#pop-up').html('<img src="popup/' + file + '.gif" /><br>' + discr);
        }
    });
    $('#pop-up').show();

    return false
    a.preventDefault();
});
});
```

And heres what my links look like

```
<div id="pops">
 <a href="content.asp?page=ns2.6">link 1</a><br>
 <a href="content.asp?page=ns3.8">link 2</a><br>
 <a href="content.asp?page=jp1.0">link 3</a><br>
 <a href="content.asp?page=jp1.0b">link 4</a><br>
 <a href="content.asp?page=jp2.1">link 5</a><br>
</div>
<div id="pop-up"></div>    ​
```

And then my plain .txt file just looks like this

```
ns2.6 - Some rather interesting details about NS 2.6
ns3.8 - Some rather interesting details about NS 3.8
jp1.0 - Some interesting details about JP 1.0
jp1.0b - More interesting details about JP 1.0b
jp2.1 - Some interesting details about JP 2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
var discr = (msg).match(new RegExp(file+' - (.*)\n'))[1];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/CJpsB/

Your last line in the text file will have to be an empty line or else the last file would not match.